# MySQL 5.7: System.Data.StrongTypingException when adding or updating an EDMX model

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, mysql-5.7

I try to get the Entity Framework (5 or 6) working with MySQL 5.7 (database first), but adding an Entity Data Model for a (test) database results in the error "Unexpected exception occured when generating the model. StrongTypingException: The value for column 'IsPrimaryKey' in table TableDetails is DBNull.". The table has a primary key by the way:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In my attempts to get to the source of this issue I tried some combinations:

- MySQL **5.6** with the **EF 5** works. I can add, update and use an EDMX model.
- MySQL **5.6** with the **EF 6** works partly. When adding an EDMX model the wizard crashes. I can add a model for the EF 5, update EF to 6, install the Nuget package 'MySql.Data.Entity' and update the EDMX model to the EF 6. The model works when running the application. But trying to update the model from the database results in an exception.
- After creating an **EF 6** model like above and using it on a machine with **MySQL 5.7** the model works, but updating (again) results in the StrongTypingException.

I hope that this issue can somehow be solved via some MySQL configuration. I already tried `show_compatibility_56=ON` on the machine with MySQL 5.7. Did not help.

Comment: Did you ever solve your own problem???  I'm having the exact same problem.  If you resolved it, I would love to +1 your question and answer.

Comment: No, I did not solve. I worked around by using MySQL 5.6 and EF 5.

Comment: :( ... oh well.  Would have been nice.  I was able to get EF6 and MySQL working together by code-first mapping, which is not as painful as it sounds...crossing my fingers that I don't hit any other road-blocks.

Answer (score 4):

Update a 3rd time: Execute the queries below: you need BOTH global and non-global switches to be OFF. I have proved these to work on VS2015 + EF6.1.3 + MySql 5.7.12

```
use <<database name>>;
set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';
set optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';
```

**After settings these values you do NEED to restart Visual Studio before attempting to create EDMX.**

If you don't see results go check if both variables are correctly set by:

```
select @@optimizer_switch;
select @@GLOBAL.optimizer_switch;
```

Both queries should give you a result with "derived_merge=off" found at the end of the variable value string.

NOTE: If you restart the server these values needs to be set again because the derived_merge optimizer_switch is default to be ON.

Reference: There has been active discussion on this BUG for EF6.1.3 and MySql 5.7
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79163

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer to the problem, but a work-around that seems to be working.

I had similar problems with trying to get the ADO.NET mapping to work.  However, I was able to manually create my POCO entities and create the `DbSet<>` code manually, which allowed me to successfully query my database.  Here's a quick how-to do the setup, which is really quite painless.

http://lvasquez.github.io/2014/11/18/EntityFramework-MySql/

Then, I used this guide to learn how to do additional attributes to map my data further:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#TableColumn

After doing the above for a couple of entities, I noticed that when I would run my tests to query the data and run debugging...exceptions were being thrown and then caught by the MySQL code having to do with a missing __migrations.  I wasn't really sure how to fix that, but I also don't want EF doing automatic migrations. So, following some other help on the web, I configured EF to disable automatic migrations and not do database initialization:

To turn off automatic migrations, I put this class in the project with my implementation of DbContext:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Then, to disable database initialization (which is what was actually throwing the error, I put this in my app.config (inside the `<entityFramework>` configuration tag):

```
<contexts>
  <context type="My.Model.MyDbContext, My.Model" disableDatabaseInitialization="true"/>
</contexts>
```

I'm not quite sure that I did everything the "best way," but that got rid of the exceptions for me.

Answer (score -3):

MySql does not support EF-5 Only Supports on MS SQL

Comment: This answer is not accurate.  The MySQL site even shows steps necessary for EF6 compatibility. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html